# asp.net Webforms Bundling & minification - Bundled script throws 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, bundling-and-minification, system.web.optimization

I have been trying to implement bundling and minification for my existing asp.net webforms project and unfortunately it is ending up with 404 responses.

Let me first share the steps I have followed.

1. Installed `System.Web.Optimization` through nuget.
2. Added `BundleConfig` class and registered it on Glabal.asax Application_Start event

My code to bundle the JS files.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modelJs").Include( 
    "~/src/model.js", 
    "~/src/calender.js", 
    "~/src/common.js", 
    "~/src/insurance.js"));
```

...

3. Added following markup to aspx page

> ```
>  <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server"> 
>     <%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modelJs") %> 
>     </asp:PlaceHolder>
> ```

4. set BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; in bundleConfig and the url formed is

> http://localhost:9011/bundles/modelJs/?v=xNmmFhbzC1isUARLQne-XoBRkWBWApbnRQX8AGvNxQY1

I have also checked the sample project which gets added in VS2013 webforms application and surprisingly, it seems to be working fine.

I have seen many questions with similar problems on SO but was not able to solve it.

Comment: As discussed in chat, the generated URL looks wrong, with a slash between "modelJs" and the query string. You confirmed there were no rewrite rules in place, the same issue exists without the <asp:Placeholder> wrapping the Render(), and that navigating to the /bundles/modelJs URL directly doesn't display anything. I'm still stumped!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the solution turns out to be very simple. Just added '/' after bundling folder which is `modeljs` in this case.

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modelJs/").Include(
```

Unfortunately, I didn't find this in any available source codes so I ended up wasting a lot of time. :-/

Comment: You got it right! I don't care if someone does not like thanks in this site. Thank you!